# Adding logic to view causes parse error?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a view that looks something like the following:

```
@foreach(var project in @Model.Projects.OrderBy(t=>t.ProjectTypeId))
{
   <h4>@project.ProjectType.Name</h4>
   <table class="table table-hover">
   ...
  </table>
}
```

Which works fine.  I wanted to add some logic around the portion that creates the table:

```
@foreach(var project in @Model.Projects.OrderBy(t=>t.ProjectTypeId))
{
   bool renderTable = true;
   if(renderTable)
   {    
      <h4>@project.ProjectType.Name</h4>
      <table class="table table-hover">
   }
   ...
    @if(renderTable)
    {
        </table>
    }
}
```

But this is causing a parse error:

```
Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: The foreach block is missing a closing "}" character.  Make sure you have a matching "}" character for all the "{" characters within this block, and that none of the "}" characters are being interpreted as markup.


Source Error: 


Line 15: 
Line 16: 
Line 17: @foreach(var project in @Model.Projects.OrderBy(t=>t.ProjectTypeId))
Line 18: {
```

Can anyone see what would cause this?  When I search for matching brackets in Visual Studio everything seems legit.

Comment: One of your `if-statements` is missing the `@` symbol.

Comment: Which one - the first one?  Isn't that part of the code block that is initiated in the `for `loop?

Comment: @DrewKennedy, Once you're already in a `@foreach` block, no need for `@if`. In fact, the compiler will throw if you do `@if`.

Comment: Is it not required? I was always under the impression it was. Well there you have it, I learned something.

Comment: Usually, *it is* required, because you're in the middle of some HTML code. But once back in the realm of C# (`@foreach`), it is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't close the `<table>` element, Razor is considering the ending `}` to be part of the HTML hence the `@if {` block is not closed.

Try this:

```
@:<table class="table table-hover">
```

Or:

```
if (renderTable)
{    
   <text>
       <h4>@project.ProjectType.Name</h4>
       <table class="table table-hover">
   </text>
}
```

Comment: I do close the table element - sorry. I left it out for the sake of brevity, but I will add it back in to clarifyh

Comment: You do close it, but outside the scope of the first `if`, so Razor is unable to tell where your HTML ends and C# taking over.

Comment: Ok - i'm on the right track with `@:` - but what exactly is this doing?

Comment: It explicitly instruct Razor to emit the following line as a string, regardless of the current context of matched HTML structure. See http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-%28c%29

Comment: Abe, give this a look (near the top of the page): http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax